# function that outputs a unique in such a way that function(A,B) = function(B,A)

Tags: cryptography

how would you make a function that will give me a unique output from two inputs in such a way that the order of inputs does not matter? like function(A,B) = function(B,A)

A and B are strings

Comment: What types are A and B?

Comment: What is the relation with Cryptography here. `F(a,b) = a+b`

Comment: In general, "function" is called a binary operator, and the property you seek is referred to as the *commutative* property.

Comment: There are many, many ways to achieve this. There are simple commutative operators that everybody is familiar with like + and *. There are also more complex ones, like e.g. let A **OP** B = SHA256(X || Y) = B **OP** A, where X and Y are A,B in sorted order, for some consistent ordering of your choosing.

Comment: Yep, sorting it was the first thing that came to my mind too. And a hash is required to bring the value back to normal size (otherwise just concatenation in itself would do the job). A cryptographically secure hash is of course only unique *practically speaking*.

Answer (score 0):

interpret A and B as integers, and return the A-th prime number times the B-th prime number.

E.g. suppose `primes = 2,3,5,7,...`, then:

```
f(2,3) = f(3,2) = 3*5 = 15
```

Comment: Finding A-th prime is not easy but next primes is.

Comment: @kelalaka OP didn't say it needs to be easy to compute. I take the question as a theoretical one.